# Is it OK to rely on an SQLiteConstraint and let SQLite do the checking for me? Is there a catch?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, insert, constraints

I have an SQLite database in Android and I use a `ContentProvider` to handle the operations, which are persisted to a table with a UNIQUE qualifier in a column.

***Problem:***

However, when I `insert` duplicated values into the database, it doesn't break my code per se, but it still spits thousands of `SQLiteConstraintException` Log lines, and to my user that just feels like polluting the Log, something unpolished. I've tried catching the exception just to experiment, but it still logs.

***Question:***

So, how do I silent those log lines? Is that even possible?

Please read the comment below for the reason to ask the question.

***Error:***

Time column has the `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
Error inserting Factor=2.0 Time=1325375465000 Extra=none
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
    at mypackage.myapp.provider.DataProvider.bulkInsert(DataProvider.java:353)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkInsert(ContentProvider.java:179)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.bulkInsert(ContentResolver.java:646)
    at mypackage.myapp.service.MyService.onHandleIntent(MyService.java:96)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: I'm feeling that this all means that what I'm trying to do is a lazy way to recover from a duplicated insert on a unique constraint, hence the "unpolished" feel in the log. I'm probably better fixing whatever is creating the duplicated entries (and calling the inserts) to begin with. I'm all for smoothness.

But that raises the question (to me): why we can't just safely "offload" work to the constraint checker and let it fail log-silently? Just in case we want... maybe we expect duplicates... so nothing to worry about. Maybe our data source, outside of our control is defective to begin with...

Comment: Commenting after answered: as I said, I was being lazy on purpose, for the purposes of this question, as I was trying not to code the checks and leave it to SQLite wondering about 1) safety (concurrency), 2) efficiency (is sqlite better/faster than me on that? probably) and also 3) practically (less code). However, some things caught my mind (the insert row count) so I implemented the dups check myself in addition to the constraints. Anyway, I ended up very satisfied with my code regarding (1). Remember that when reading this question.

Comment: If you are not utilizing android.util.Log yourself, then why are you concerned about logging errors to the user?

Comment: Well... It's not Log itself, but the fact that the log implies that I'm not being efficient enough. The Log is the symptom, not what I'm worried about.

Comment: I see.  You said: "to my user that just feels like polluting the Log".   Hence the clarification.

Comment: I know, I understood your point. Polluted log lines were the symptom to some inefficiency, sorry if I wasn't clear, but I'm glad you now understood what I meant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can formulate or modify the SQL yourself, either for `INSERT` or for the initial `CREATE TABLE`, you can use SQLite's [conflict handling extensions](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).  There are two options for how to do this:

- When you insert, use `INSERT OR IGNORE` rather than just `INSERT`. You can also use `OR REPLACE`, `OR ABORT`, or any of several other reactions.
- When you create the table, specify an `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` clause for the `UNIQUE` constraint. That will cause inserts or updates which violate the constraint to silently do nothing.

I find the idea of using `INSERT OR IGNORE`/`INSERT OR REPLACE` to handle duplicate data, particularly in concurrent environments, to be very clean. It checks for duplication once - in the database - and avoids race conditions where you check for existence first (admittedly not a problem if only one process/thread is accessing the database).

However, if the duplicates are a result of a bug (rather than duplicate events/actions that your code is just not explicitly de-duplicating), then this could just be hiding the bug rather than fixing it. Lack of explicit de-dulication, however, is not a bug in my opinion. So if the fix is to check for duplicates, use the database; if the real problem is that they were generated in the first place (at the actual application level, not the database row level), then I would probably look for that problem.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I had in mind. I also noticed that if I use `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` on the table schema, Android's `SQLiteDatabase.insert(String, String, ContentValues)` will report the row as inserted... so be careful if you need that. And yes, considering I have multiple services downloading stuff, it also has the benefit of avoiding race conditions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can leave it and as you say you could fix it. In my opinion it depends whether the dups are exceptional occurences or 'just happen because you're being lazy'.

I think that in the main it costs less to cleanse data at the entry to a module than to deal with it afterwards. However how you define the cost is down to you.

Comment: Most of the dups aren't, but some of them could be fixed by me before even triggering the service downloader. I agree about checking at entry point. However, I'm far from finishing the code, and I was asking this also in a "what-if" perspective.